# Unable to parse the result returned by NSAppleScript method executeAndReturnError

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

This is the code which i am using:

```
NSDictionary *errorInfo=nil;
NSString *source=@"tell application \"Mail\"\nget name of mailbox of every account\nend tell";
NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *aDescriptor=[[NSAppleEventDescriptor alloc]init];
aDescriptor=[run executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
[aDescriptor coerceToDescriptorType:'utxt'];
NSLog(@"result:%@",[aDescriptor stringValue]);
```

Output which i got:
result:(null)

Please help me anyone on this.Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 4):

IIRC that will return a list descriptor filled with list descriptors. You need to iterate over them and pull out the info you want. You're also initializing a descriptor and then immediately overwriting its pointer. Do something like (untested):

```
NSDictionary *errorInfo = nil;
NSString *source = @"tell application \"Mail\"\nget name of mailbox of every account\nend tell";
NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *aDescriptor = [run executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
NSInteger num = [aDescriptor numberOfItems];

// Apple event descriptor list indexes are one-based!
for (NSInteger idx = 1; idx <= num; ++idx) {
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *innerListDescriptor = [aDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:idx];

    NSInteger innerNum = [innerListDescriptor numberOfItems];

    for (NSInteger innerIdx = 1; innerIdx <= innerNum; ++innerIdx) {
        NSString *str = [[innerListDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:innerIdx] stringValue];
        // Do something with str here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** version, tested in 2022:

```
func run(appleScript: String) {
    var error: NSDictionary? = nil
    if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: appleScript) {
            
        let output = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
            
        // Print All Values
        let numberOfItems = output.numberOfItems
        print("numberOfItems: \(numberOfItems)")
            
        for i in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let innerDescriptor = output.atIndex(i)
            print("\(i): " + (innerDescriptor?.stringValue ?? "nil"))
        }
            
        // Catch Error
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: '\(error)'")
        }
            
    } else {
        print("Error: Unable to init NSAppleScript")
    }
}
```